# Foundation 4 Orbit Initialization Error

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm a bit new to Foundation 4 and the Orbit plugin, but I can't figure out why the orbit plugin will not initialize. I've got the compass version of foundation 4 installed.

The zepto.js and jquery.js are in javascripts/vendor/, and the foundation.orbit.js file is in javascripts/foundation/

Modernizr

```
<script src="javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

Orbit Plugin:

```
<!-- Orbit Slides and Object -->

<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
    <span class="preloader"></span>
<ul data-orbit>
  <li>
    <img src="placehold.it/1000x400" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="placehold.it//1000x400" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="placehold.it/1000x400" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The page can be found here:
http://foundationtest.tx0rx0.com/tx0rx0/testpage.html

I've got modernizr in the head, and here's what the section looks like right before the last last body tag:

```
<!-- Javascript for Orbit Image Slider -->     
    <script>
            document.write('<script src=/javascripts/vendor/'
                + ('__proto__ ' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
                + '.js><\/script>')
    </script>

<script src= "/javascripts/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src= "/javascripts/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>
<script src= "/javascripts/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Foundation -->

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I don't see it and a helpful nudge would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: First of all correct the path of your second img. "placehold.it//1000x400" is has two backslashes

Comment: @alkis OT, but those are forward slashes; \ is a backslash

Comment: Yup you are right :P. Thnx for that, I'm going to edit my answer.  What does OT mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the path of your scripts is not right.

```
<script src= "/javascripts/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src= "/javascripts/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>
<script src= "/javascripts/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
```

And here

```
document.write('<script src=/javascripts/vendor/'
                + ('__proto__ ' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
                + '.js><\/script>')
```

Check the slash.

```
<script src="javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

Here you don't have it. One of them must be wrong.

And the path of your second img. `"placehold.it//1000x400"` is has two slashes

**EDIT**
I checked your site. Remove the first slash from your foundation js path

**UPDATE**
Just remove this

```
<span class="preloader"></span>
```

Comment: That and adding http:// to the placehold.it appear to have fixed it partially. Now the image loads, but the preloader circly thingy doesn't go away

Comment: That wasn't part of the question. Your question was, why it doesn't load.

Comment: I'm not implying it was, but I was asking if you knew what caused that

Comment: Alright, I'll let you go. In the foundation docs here, under Graceful Loading and Preloader: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html They seemed to say that it would only appear before the image loaded. I can just remove it, but is there an easy way to do what they say?

Comment: Problem is I haven't used orbit before so I can't really help. Besides it's a completely different question. You must create a new one. It will be simpler for future OPs to find the answer given if they have the same problem as you did. Even if I knew you still should open a new question (but I really don't).

Comment: Thanks anyway. Have a great week